# vertically align emoji in div on Mac

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, emoji

Is it possible to perfectly and vertically align emoji in a div on Mac?

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the div is 50px tall, and the emoji is 50px tall, but the head sticks out above the div rather than being perfectly and vertically centered within it.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czyus6gh/).

As you can see, my div is simple and contains only the code for the emoji:

```
<div>&#x1F464;</div>
```

I tried adding a bunch of vertical centering styles to the div to no avail:

```
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f00;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

Oddly enough the above code renders perfectly fine on Windows because their emoji align with the baseline of the font.

Comment: Did you try decrease `font-size`?

Comment: Yes, decreasing or increasing `font-size` does not remove the imperfection, although decreasing the `font-size` makes the imperfection harder to see.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, the little bit of offset in top spacing here is caused from the **Glyph** itself and would need to be adjusted via `transform: translate` or negative margin.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: red 1px solid;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
}

#div1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#div2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#div3 {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
Yep...
<div id="div1"></div>

<br/>

Yep again.
<div id="div2">&#x1F464;</div>

<br/>

And yep again.
<div id="div3">&#x1F464;</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the emoji is actually not vertically aligned perfectly. If you increase the font size from 2rem to 3rem, this becomes easier to see.

Comment: @LeoGalleguillos hence the first sentence comment before the example. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I moved the styles to a child element I added to surround the glyph. I removed the `line-height` property because that was throwing off cross-browser rendering and added a small amount of bottom padding to make up for the natural gap space in the glyph itself. I also added a `CSS Variable` to minimize the repetition of a repeated value. This made it easier to test at different sizes. Tested in Mac Firefox/Chrome/Safari (all latest).

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.small {
  --symbol: 50px;
}

.medium {
  --symbol: 100px;
}

.large {
  --symbol: 150px;
}

div span {
  --symbol: 50px;
  width: var(--symbol);
  height: var(--symbol);  
  font-size: var(--symbol);
  background-color: #f00;
  padding-bottom: 0.06em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="small">&#x1F464;</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="medium">&#x1F464;</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="large">&#x1F464;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I really don't like the 0.06em custom padding for this, but maybe this is the only solution.

Comment: @LeoGalleguillos Believe me, I hate it, too. I found no other way around this and was able to finally see consistent cross-browser rendering.

Answer (score -1):

Put the text in a `span` so you can target it separate from the `div`. Then remove the flexbox centering and you can get it in there with some other styles you can see here.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
div span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>&#x1F464;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The icon is not aligning flush with the bottom of the parent div in Firefox.

Comment: Your approach to using the icon is one where you can expect these cross-browser differences as you are dealing with text flow instead of a clearly defined DOM element. This is why many people opt to use actual icon fonts like Font Awesome, or SVG code to define the shape in the browser in a more predictably cross-browser manner.

Comment: Looks pretty good, however on Windows this will add extra padding. Also, we're trying to avoid using a proprietary icon font.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would approach it. The font-size on mac seems to create an image larger than 50x50, which may be the root of the problem. Hiding the overflow, will at least make the image more consistent.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="emoji">
      &#x1F464;
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f00;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.emoji {
    font-size: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pg46v8j3/2/

Comment: Ah I see, emojis will be different sizes on different os's. I dont really see a great solution for this problem, except, like other commenters said, to use a library like font-awesome.